# How can I optimize if statement any([tmp_name in C or C in tmp_name for C in ['obs', 'situ', 'observation']])?

Tags: python

I am reviewing some python code, and I have this statement in my code :

```
for column_name in Data.columns:
    tmp_name = str(column_name).lower()
    if any([tmp_name in C or C in tmp_name for C in ['obs', 'situ', 'observation']]):
        Data.rename(columns={column_name: 'Observation date'}, inplace=True)
        continue
```

There are a couple (5) of if statement like this one in the for loop. 
This if statement looks like there a more efficient way to do it.

Comment: I deleted my answer as I realised I'd made probably incorrect assumptions about the nature of the variables. I'm struggling to get my head around quite what this is supposed to do though.

Comment: I updated my post with something closer with the code i am reviewing.

Comment: So it appears that this code is 'tidying up' the column names. I'm not sure there's anything intrinsically sub-optimal about the current implementation, the question in my mind is whether this business logic is required. For example currently the column names "My Observation" or "the obs" would be replaced with "Observation Date" which seems reasonable. However, due to the `tmp_name in C or C in tmp_name` condition the column names "VAT" or "t" would also get replaced. It seems error prone unless you know all the possible original column names (in which case why not map them?)